# Books about Quantum Contextuality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations

Does anybody know some bibliography about [Quantum Contextuality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_contextuality)? Why is such a framework a generalización of Bell inequalities? Why has it something to do with hidden variables theories?

Comment: Contextuality is not a generalización of Bell inequalities. IMO It has much less value than the Bell theorem.

Comment: @Evariste Non-locality, as described by Bell's Theorem can be viewed as a generalisation of Contextuality and not the other way around.

Comment: Besides, you have too many questions, could you please be more specific about the kind of resources you are looking for?

Comment: I have already read something interesting about this question. Since Q contextual experiments can be performed with only one particle and Q entanglement ones need at least two particles, Q contextuality could be regarded as a more profound reality. But I don't know how Q contextuality denies hidden variables. I have read some papers of Adan Cabello but at some point I get lost